# getting recent sold 5 unique products

Tags: php, magento

I want to fetch recent sold 5 unique items in magento, I have below snippet of code.
 It is displaying a blank page, However when I remove `->getSelect()->group('product_id')` from the below code, It works but the items are no longer unique.

```
   $itemsCollection= Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')
        ->join('order', 'order_id=entity_id')   
        ->getSelect()->group('product_id')
        ->setOrder('order_id', 'desc')
        ->setPage(1, 5) ;
```

How do I group by these products?

Comment: Can you give examples of output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code is almost correct - the problem is down to how you are chaining the method calls together.

When chaining method calls, each call will return an object, usually a reference to the same class.  So in your example, things went wrong at the  `->getSelect()` and `->group()` calls as these return a reference to a `Varien_Db_Select` object and not a `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Item_Collection` object as you were expecting.

(Also note, it is safer to order by created_at instead of order_id for the most recent orders)

So, a working example would be...

```
// Initialise the collection
$itemsCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->getCollection()
    ->setOrder('created_at', Varien_Data_Collection::SORT_ORDER_DESC)
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')  //Change this to only select the fields you require
    ->setPage(1, 5)
;

// Separately add the GROUP BY clause
$itemsCollection->getSelect()->group('product_id');

// Now you can safely iterate over the collection
foreach($itemsCollection as $item) {
    echo $item->getData('product_id') . ' - ' . $item->getData('created_at') . '<br/>';
}
```